# How to call the same function that the ToolBar editbutton does

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

So I have created a context box upon right click that has Add/Edit/Delete Rows. I also have a bunch of code launched before the Dialog is shown. My problem is that when I use the context menu it doesn't go through some of the code. I have tried to call on the functions directly but it doesn't format correctly.

I am mainly concerned with the edit button, here is the code I am using to bring up the edit Dialog

```
 function editRow() {
     var grid = jQuery("#<%= Jqgrid1.ClientID %>");
     var rowKey = grid.getGridParam("selrow");
     if (rowKey) {
         // I have tried calling functions here and it still doesn't work
         grid.editGridRow(rowKey, grid.editDialogOptions);
     }
     else {
         alert("No rows are selected");
     }
 }
```

So if I use this to display the editform it isn't formatted correctly nor does it go through the functions all correctly.

I am using the ASP Webforms version of Jqgrid so I call the function by doing this

```
<cc1:JQGrid1 ID="Jqgrid1
 //other attributes

ClientSideEvents-BeforeEditDialogShown="ChangeMonitor" 

 //Rest of code />
```

So this works just fine, and I'm trying to get the Edit button on the context menu to display correctly.

My thought was to use Jquery to trigger a click on the actual Edit button once someone used the context menu. I couldn't find an ID that would work however.

Is there an easy way to connect my context menu Edit button, with the actual Edit button in the toolbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found a solution to my problem.

The id field of the button was edit_ct100_cpMainContent_Jqgrid1_top so I just triggered a click with this code.

```
$("td[id^=edit][id$=top]").trigger("click")
```

For some reason when I used the _ct100_cpMainContent_Jqgrid1 it wasn't working, but now it does. Hope this helps someone.